# EventHubTrigger parameters in a custom section of local.settings.json

Tags: azure-functions

I want to put EventHubTrigger parameters in a **custom section** of local.settings.json file.
For example:

```
{
 "IsEncrypted": false,
 "Values": {
   ...NOT HERE!
 },
 "EventHub": {
    "ConnectionString": "Endpoint=sb://=",
    "Name": "test",
    "ConsumerGroup": "test"
 }
}
```

And then refer these parameters in EventHubTrigger somehow:

```
[FunctionName("EventHubConsumer")]
public async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("%EventHub:Name%", ConsumerGroup = "%EventHub:ConsumerGroup%", Connection = "EventHub:ConnectionString")] string[] messages)
{
        ...
}
```

And then refer these parameters in Azure function configuration.

Is it possible?

How about to pass configuration to EventHubTrigger as a POCO config object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to put EventHubTrigger parameters in a custom section of **local.settings.json** file. And then refer these parameters in EventHubTrigger somehow. Is it possible?

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#local-settings-file) microsoft reference doc, 
app settings used by azure functions need to be defined in the `Values` section of the `local.settings.json` only.

> How about to pass configuration to EventHubTrigger as a POCO config object?

`EventHubTrigger` does not support a POCO `configuration` object to be passed during binding. (you may refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=csharp#configuration) Microsoft reference doc). Any attributes that need to be assigned values for this trigger, need to make use of app settings (in the form of local.settings.json locally).

For something that you are trying to do in the `EventHubTrigger` i.e.

```
public async Task Run([EventHubTrigger("%EventHub:Name%", ConsumerGroup = "%EventHub:ConsumerGroup%", Connection = "EventHub:ConnectionString")] string[] messages)
```

writing app settings in the `Values` section as follows should work-

```
"Values":{
.
.
"EventHub:Name": "your event hub name",
"EventHub:ConsumerGroup": "your event hub consumer group",
"EventHub:ConnectionString": "your event hub connection string"
}
```